# Can't get rvest to log in to website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm new to using `rvest`.  I'm trying to log in to a website which requires `username` and `password`.

```
library(rvest)
url       <-"https://mc04.manuscriptcentral.com/ip-iop"   ## page to spider
pgsession <-html_session(url)               ## create session
pgform    <-html_form(pgsession)[[1]] 
filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
                          USERID = "NOTMYUSERNAME", 
                          PASSWORD = "NOTMYPASSWORD")
```

I get:

> Error: Unknown field names: USERID, PASSWORD

Looking at pgform I get:

```
'<form> 'default_form' (POST )
      <input hidden> 'BROWSER_SUPPORTED': N
      <input hidden> 'JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED': N
      <input hidden> 'NEXT_PAGE': 
      <input hidden> 'orgs':  null'
```

Any ideas of how to get this working?

Comment: Rvest probably isn't going to remember state so logging in probably isn't going to help if you need a page directly after the one you submit to. You probably need to use [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html) to fake an interactive web session.

Comment: _"Rvest probably isn't going to remember state"_. If "state" is handled by session cookies (most sites do that), it will most certainly remember state.

Comment: That URL has `User-agent: * <newline> Disallow: /` in `robots.txt`. That means no scraping. https://mc04.manuscriptcentral.com/robots.txt

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll look into RSelenium - would that work even with the no scraping setup of the website?